# Redirect 301 error url wile Cutting "+"

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-301

My URL is: `www.domain.com/url/url/+`

I want redirect a `301` error to www.domain.com/url//url/

I've tried this method does not work:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /+(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1
```

nor does:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /(.*)/(.*)/+(.*)  http://www.domain.com$1
```

What method could I use? To cut the `+` in `www.domain.com/url/+` to make it show `www.domain.com/url`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule to remove `+` from anywhere in an URI:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.+?)\+(.*)$ /$1$2
```

Answer (score 0):

Hence RedirectMatch uses Regex, + is ment for one or more of the char infront of it.
You should use + instead.

Answer (score 0):

The `+` needs to be escaped because it's a reserved character for "one or more":

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.*)\+ http://www.domain.com/$1
```

Comment: not working, it's Redirect www.domain.comurl/url/ But I want Redirect to www.domain.com/url/url/

Comment: @user3282262 there's a slash right after `www.domain.com`. Why would it go away?